# Symfony Forms add placeholder to the prototype of collection field

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, twig, placeholder

I'm looking for a way to add placeholders to the collection field prototype. Adding the attribute 'placeholder' does not make any effect.
I tried using prototype_data and replacing the value-attribute with placeholder in twig, but it throws an error if field type is a number, and passed text value can't be converter to a number.

```
$builder->add('fees', CollectionType::class, [
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'delete_empty' => true,
            'entry_type' => TextType::class,
            'prototype' => true,
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Fee Type',
            ],
        ])
```

Comment: move the `attr` option into `entry_options`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can embed any available option for the Form Type specified in `entry_type` option (in your case `TextType`) to all the entries of your `CollectionType` through the `entry_options`.

Specifically for your problem you should use this:

```
$builder->add('fees', CollectionType::class, [
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'delete_empty' => true,
        'entry_type' => TextType::class,
        'prototype' => true,
        'entry_options' => [
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Fee Type',
            ]
        ]
    ])
```

Documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-options)